# my output [menu1,menu2,menu3] arraylist store in database i want remove[,] in php

Tags: php

i can send arraylist android to php throug url . that arraylist can store in database also.but it include [ at start ]at end. i want to remove brakets first and last

```
        here my code is given

         <?php
         $arr=explode(',',preg_replace('/^.*\[(.*)\].*$/','$1',$_POST['menuname']));
         mysql_connect("localhost","root","mobixmysql");
         mysql_select_db("test");
         foreach($arr as $value){
         mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (menuname) VALUES ('" . 
         mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "')")or
         die('unable'.mysql_error());
         echo "inserted";
         }
         ?>
```

my database stored [menu1 in first row in menuname column,menu2 in second column at last] in mysql database how to remove brakets first and last ..please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
     $arr=explode(',',preg_replace('/^.*\[(.*)\].*$/','$1',trim($_POST['menuname'], '[]')));
     mysql_connect("localhost","root","mobixmysql");
     mysql_select_db("test");
     foreach($arr as $value){
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (menuname) VALUES ('" . 
     mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "')")or
     die('unable'.mysql_error());
     echo "inserted";
     }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
trim($string, '[]');
```

where $string = [menu1, menu2, menu3....]